# Python pandas Increment CSV cell value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Using python language and pandas, how can I manipulate an existing CSV cell to always plus 1 to the cell value when my if statement is true?

```
>while True
>   if xxx = TRUE
>      "open existing CSV and take the value of A1 and increment by +1"
```

Comment: Without a clear example and logic description, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: 1)  A CSV file does not have cells, it is text. 2) `A1` is spreadsheet notation and a spreadsheet file != CSV. You need to provide more information to have any hope of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
A = list(range(10))
B = [a%3==0 for a in A]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A, 'B':B})
df['A+1 if B True'] = df['A'] + df['B'] * 1
```

Comment: Since `1 + True == 2` and `1 + False == 1`, you could drop the last `* 1`

Comment: yes, but it is more readable.  and if you want to change it later to 4 it will be straight forward.